# Symfony2, Doctrine2 Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association sth#category, but expecting sth

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Now I have problem with submitting post data in my form (my forms looks like:

```
Task: <input text>
Category: <multiple select category>
DueDate: <date>
<submit>
```

)
And after submitting my form, I'll get this error:

```
Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task#category, but expecting Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category
```

### My sources:

**Task Object** <kbd>Task.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tasks") 
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;              

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)    
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *      message = "Task cannot be empty"      
     * )    
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = "3",
     *      minMessage = "Task is too short"         
     * )     
     */     
    protected $task;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")    
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
     */
    protected $dueDate;

    /**
     * @Assert\True(message = "You have to agree")    
     */         
    protected $accepted;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="tasks")                       
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set task
     *
     * @param string $task
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setTask($task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get task
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }

    /**
     * Set dueDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dueDate
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setDueDate($dueDate)
    {
        $this->dueDate = $dueDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dueDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDueDate()
    {
        return $this->dueDate;
    }

    /**
     * Add category
     *
     * @param \Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Task
     */
    public function addCategory(\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->category[] = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove category
     *
     * @param \Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category $category
     */
    public function removeCategory(\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->category->removeElement($category);
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

**Category Object** <kbd>Category.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories") 
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")             
     */
    protected $id; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, unique=true)   
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="Choose a category", groups = {"adding"})                   
     */         
    protected $name;  

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $tasks;            


    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->name);
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tasks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add tasks
     *
     * @param \Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task $tasks
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addTask(\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task $tasks)
    {
        $this->tasks[] = $tasks;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tasks
     *
     * @param \Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task $tasks
     */
    public function removeTask(\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task $tasks)
    {
        $this->tasks->removeElement($tasks);
    }

    /**
     * Get tasks
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTasks()
    {
        return $this->tasks;
    }
}
```

**TaskType** <kbd>TaskType.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type\Category;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('task', 'text', array('label' => 'Task'))
                ->add('dueDate', 'date', array('label' => 'Due Date'))
                ->add('category', new CategoryType(), array('validation_groups' => array('adding')))
                //->add('accepted', 'checkbox')
                ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'task';
    }
}
```

**CategoryType** <kbd>CategoryType.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
                      'class' => 'AcmeTaskBundle:Category',
                      'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC'); },
                      'property' => 'name',
                      'multiple' => true,
                      'label' => 'Categories',
                      ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'category';
    }
}
```

and my **Controller** <kbd>DefaultController.php</kbd>:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write name here...');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createForm('task', $task);                   
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'success',
            'Task was successfuly created'
        );
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        /*
        $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Category')->findOneByName($form->get('category')->getData());
        $task->setCategory($category);
        */
        $em->persist($task);
        try {
            $em->flush();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            // sth
        }

        //$nextAction = $form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked() ? 'task_new' : 'task_success';

        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($nextAction));
    } 

    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

So, I looked at this problem at the google, but there were different kinds of problems. Any idea?

**UPDATE**
Full error message:

```
[2013-09-30 14:43:55] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task#category, but expecting Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category" at /var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 762 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException: Found entity of type Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection on association Acme\\TaskBundle\\Entity\\Task#category, but expecting Acme\\TaskBundle\\Entity\\Category at /var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:762)"} []
```

**UPDATE 2**

My TWIG template <kbd>new.html.twig</kbd>

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Task create</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('success') %}
<div style="display: block; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid green; margin: 15px; width: 450px;">
{{ flashMessage }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

{{ form_start(form, {'action': path ('task_new'), 'method': 'POST', 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate' }}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form) }}

  <div>
    {{ form_label(form.task) }}:<br>  
    {{ form_widget(form.task) }} {{ form_errors(form.task) }}<br>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{ form_label(form.category) }}:<br>
    {{ form_widget(form.category) }} {{ form_errors(form.category) }}   
  </div>
  <div>
    {{ form_label(form.dueDate) }}:<br>
    {{ form_widget(form.dueDate) }} {{ form_errors(form.dueDate) }}<br>
  </div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add a Stacktrace where this error is coming from?

Comment: See my updated question (bottom)

Comment: Could you check what kind of objects / collections are in your $task->getCategory(), right before you persist? and maybe debug in your task if the form component is using the Task::addCategory or Task::setCategory method.

Comment: it throws an exception before if form is validated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can improve the controller code by changing your setters in the entities:

In `Task`:

```php
public function addCategory(Category $category)
{
    if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
        $this->categories->add($category);
        $category->addTask($this); // Fix this
    }
}
```

And in `Category`:

```php
public function addTask(Task $task)
{
    if (!this->tasks->contains($task)) {
        $this->tasks->add($task);
        $task->addCategory($this);
    }
}
```

This will keep the elements in the `ArrayCollection` unique so you won't have to do that checking in your code and will also set the inverse side automatically.

Answer (score 2):

So I found my solution! This code works:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('task', 'text', array('label' => 'Task'))
            ->add('dueDate', 'date', array('label' => 'Date', 'format' => 'ddMMMMyyyy'))
            ->add('category', 'entity', array('required' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'class' => 'AcmeTaskBundle:Category', 'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC'); },))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Send'));
}
```

And my controller is working in this form:

```
if($form->isValid())
{
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
        'success',
        'Task successfuly added'
    );
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    foreach($form->get('category')->getData() as $cat)
    {
        $task->removeCategory($cat);
        $task->addCategory($cat);
    }
    $em->persist($task);
    try {
        $em->flush();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        // sth
    }
}
```

I'm forced to use `$task->removeCategory($cat)` because I'll get error of dublication primary indexes if it will not be here.

Now I'm trying to resolve my problem with embedded and non-embedded forms -> [Symfony2, validation embedded and non-embedded forms with same parameters and different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190344/symfony2-validation-embedded-and-non-embedded-forms-with-same-parameters-and-di)

I believe that my questions will be helpful for beginners with Symfony2 having same problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a manyToMany relationship from task to category, which means you can have more than one category for each task. If you are trying to have multiple categories in a task, you can try changing this line

```
->add('category', new CategoryType(), array('validation_groups' => array('adding')))
```

for something like

```
->add('category', 'collection', array('type' => new CategoryType()))
```

check symfony's documentation on [form collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and [this cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#cookbook-form-collections-new-prototype)

Comment: Hello, if I do it, I'll get a blank place to my form widget of category. `<div>
    <label class="required">Category</label>:<br>
    <div id="task_category"></div>       
  </div>`

Comment: can you add your twig template? you should add something in the twig file to add your categories. You should add a prototype to the collection container...

Comment: Try something like: `<div>
    {{ form_label(form.category) }}:<br>
    {% for category in form.category %}
            <li>{{ form_row(category.name) }}</li>
        {% endfor %} 
  </div>`

Comment: I had 0 DB queries after my form was rendered. Expected 1 for selection of categories from DB.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try to add a setCategory method to your Task entity, because currently you only have the add function and thats why the form component is calling the addFunction instead of the set for the whole arraycollection.

Comment: And what i should write to this method?

Comment: `public function setCategory($categories){ $this->category = $categories  }`

Comment: I think you mean `public function setCategory(\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category $category) { $this->category = $category; }` because i don't use propery $categories but it doesn't helps.

Comment: No I actually meant what I wrote. Just try to remove the Type from the function, because $this->category is NOT a single category, but a collection of categories.

Comment: yes, i called it $category not $categories and i know it is not a single.

Comment: so have you tried: `public function setCategory($category) { $this->category = $category; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your form.

Your task have ManyToMany relation with categotry and stored in field `category`(logical it is a categories). But in the form you set '->add('category', new CategoryType())' which means that you add new type that is a array or something(data_class not defined) and this type contains another one field.

Solution is to directly define field in your form(without using standalone form type) Or extend *category form type* from entity type(by default type extended form type).

Comment: If i use data_class i'll get error message at the start of rendering my page. Error message is like current - ArrayCollection got, expected Category entity. And can you show me an example how can I extend form type (in my case - category)?