# Symfony2, validation embedded and non-embedded forms with same parameters and different results?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this form builder:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('task', 'text', array('label' => 'Task'))
                ->add('dueDate', 'date', array('label' => 'Date', 'format' => 'ddMMMMyyyy'))
                ->add('category', 'entity', array('required' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'class' => 'AcmeTaskBundle:Category', 'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC'); },))
                ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Send'));
    }
```

and it works successful with this controller:

```
if($form->isValid())
{
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
        'success',
        'Task successfuly added'
    );
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    foreach($form->get('category')->getData() as $cat)
    {
        $task->removeCategory($cat);
        $task->addCategory($cat);
    }
    $em->persist($task);
    try {
        $em->flush();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        // sth
    }
}
```

**BUT**

if I try to embed my form with field category like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('task', 'text', array('label' => 'Task'))
            ->add('dueDate', 'date', array('label' => 'Date', 'format' => 'ddMMMMyyyy'))
            ->add('category', new CategoryType())
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Send'));
}
```

where my CategoryType looks like:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        //'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Category',
        'csrf_protection' => true,
    ));
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
                  'class' => 'AcmeTaskBundle:Category',
                  'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC'); },
                  //'property' => 'name',
                  'multiple' => true,
                  'required' => true,
                  ));
}
```

it returns an Exception instance of Category expected, ArrayCollection given. **Why** the "same" form is working only if it is not embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two types are not the same. In the first case you use option `'multiple' => true` that means that form expects collection of Category entity. From your controller I see that you have (One|Many)-To-Many relation Task-Category. Category here is ArrayCollection of Category entities and therefore your form is working.

In the second case you have `->add('category', new CategoryType())` that means that Category can be the only one, according to your controller and Task entity it is not true. You need to create collection of `CategoryType()` here.

```
->add('category', 'collection', array('type' => new CategoryType()))
```

Also I think you must provide this line with more options to fit your application.

Comment: I'm using many to many relation. Not one category to many tasks.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You have (One|Many)-To-Many relation. You have MANY categories.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I'll try it, now I don't have access on my computer, where are my files. I'll give you the informations then.

Comment: So there it is: blank field in the Category label. There is no select, or anything else. 0 queries (1 expected for selection from DB for category list).

Comment: The problem is solved. You have started describe a new problem: "Why does the collection of CategoryType have no form rendered?".
To find answer on this question you should read article http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: But there is using JavaScript without input selection. I think it is so difficult for that, so I just stay without embedding forms and each type will be a different form.

Comment: I had similar problem... I've just wrote my own form templates to represent my collections as I want. But the choice is yours;)
Don't forget to mark this answer as right;)